# Noise floor flatness in IQ FFT window

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

I am doing a simple $P_{in}$ - $P_{out}$ linearity test for my RF generator/receiver system. The generator provides an IQ modulated CW single tone with $P = - 80dBm$ at 1 GHz.

If we look at the RF front end of the detector;

- We see that RF input is first shifted to IF band ([diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEE0r.png)), then adjusted to cover ADC full range and filtered before ADC.
- ADC has $f_{sample} = 250\,\text{MHz}$. Also, the device allows $f_{sample}$ down to 10 kHz.

[image]

When I check out the PSD window in FFT Analyzer, I observe the presence of the transmitted signal and that's fine.

What I also observe is the noise floor roll-off on both ends of the PSD figure.(below) For several sampling frequencies up to 100 MHz, the onset is at  ~ 80% $f_s/2$. Then, for the range covered at $f_s = 250 MHz$,  we observe that the flatness is severely degraded.

- What is this phenomenon? Can you explain the mechanism behind it ?

[image]

Comment: So If I understand this right you are sampling a sinusoid at 1 GHz directly with a 100MhZ or 250Mhz sampling rate?

Comment: No. The sinusoid is first shifted to IF band before sampling. The full diagram of the RF Digitizer board can be found [here](https://imgur.com/s83SPDo) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFDk.png)

Comment: @krlngc, ok, then please add these details regarding the IF frequency being used, because it is not obvious from the question.

Comment: Also, what band of RF Frequencies are going into the 3 IF Paths (one of them being directly passed)?

Comment: There is a 62.5, 187.5 MHz IF. If the sinusoid lies in these IFs the two sided or actual signal bandwidth is till 125 and 375 MHz respectively. You mention that sampling rate at maximum is 250MHz which is not good enough for both IFs. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you show the full digital spectrum for all four cases and clarify which of the bandpass filter options you are using?